# Retrieving single data from Nested Struct in go: Is there any simple way to do that?

Tags: html, json, api, go, struct

I have this nested struct i want to get only single data from it and to display them to html template

```
type FamilyMembers struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name `xml:"familyMember" json:"familyMember"`
    Text         string   `xml:",chardata" json:",chardata"`
    ResponseCode string   `xml:"responseCode"`
    Family     []struct {
        Text    string `xml:",chardata" json:",chardata"`
        Parents []struct {
            Text   string `xml:",chardata" json:",chardata"`
            Parent []struct {
                Text      string `xml:",chardata" json:",chardata"`
                FirstName string `xml:"firstName" json:"firstName"`
                MidleName string `xml:"midleName" json:"midleName"`
                SurName   string `xml:"surName" json:"surName"`
                Gender    string `xml:"gender" json:"gender"`
                DoB       string `xml:"doB" json:"doB"`
            } `xml:"parent" json:"parent"`
        } `xml:"parents" json:"parents"`

        Children []struct {
            Text  string `xml:",chardata" json:",chardata"`
            Child []struct {
                Text      string `xml:",chardata" json:",chardata"`
                FirstName string `xml:"firstName" json:"firstName"`
                MidleName string `xml:"midleName" json:"midleName"`
                SurName   string `xml:"surName" json:"surName"`
                Gender    string `xml:"gender" json:"gender"`
                DoB       string `xml:"doB" json:"doB"`
            } `xml:"child" json:"child"`
        } `xml:"children" json:"children"`

    } `xml:"family" json:"family"`
}
```

I tried do the following but only it display data to the console but not on template (HTML)

```
var allID string
var mapData []string
for i := 0; i < len(responseData1.Family); i++ {
   for j := 0; j < len(responseData1.Family[i].Children); j++ {
     for k := 0; k < len(responseData1.Family[i].Children[j].Child); k++ {
    allID = responseData1.Family[i].Children[j].Child[k].ID
    if allID == id {
        fmt.Println("ID :", allID)
        mapData = append(mapData,
        responseData1.Family[i].Children[j].Child[k].FirstName,
        responseData1.Family[i].Children[j].Child[k].MidleName,
        responseData1.Family[i].Children[j].Child[k].SurName,
        responseData1.Family[i].Children[j].Child[k].Gender,
        responseData1.Family[i].Children[j].Child[k].DoB,
        )
                }
    }
     }
    for j := 0; j < len(responseData1.Family[i].Parents); j++ {
    for k := 0; k < len(responseData1.Family[i].Parents[j].Parent); k++ {
    allID = responseData1.Family[i].Parents[j].Parent[k].ID
    if allID == id {
        fmt.Println("ID :", allID)
        mapData = append(mapData,
        responseData1.Family[i].Children[j].Child[k].FirstName,
        responseData1.Family[i].Children[j].Child[k].MidleName,
        responseData1.Family[i].Children[j].Child[k].SurName,
        responseData1.Family[i].Children[j].Child[k].Gender,
        responseData1.Family[i].Children[j].Child[k].DoB,
        )
        }
    }
    }
}
```

from this i am able to get what i need but the problem is that i can not display it to html template rather i get error that template can not evaluate such data

Comment: You should show the code that sends your data to the frontend, as well as the client side code. Btw: You can iterate over your data way more easily with for .. range (https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_range)

Comment: Just as a style point, don't use anonymous struct definitions.  Declare `type Parent struct`, then `type Parents []Parent`, then `type FamilyMember struct`, etc. - build it up one piece at a time and make sure it works as you go.  What you have is neither particularly maintainable nor readable.

Are you using [go HTML templates](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template) for rendering?  It would be good to see that part of your code.